# clj-http get request: SSLException

Tags: ssl, clojure, clj-http

I'm having troubles accessing a https url via a clj-http get-request.

The same URL works perfectly with a simple curl request. In clojure, I just get it working when using the `:insecure? true` flag.

Here's the error I get otherwise:

```
SSLException Certificate for <...> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [..., ...]  org.apache.http.conn.\
ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify (AbstractVerifier.java:164)
```

Comment: What Apache HTTP Client version are you using (clj-http uses it internally)? Maybe it is related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1613?